# how to run a method after jQuery validate has been run

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Our company uses jquery validate and I want to update some fields AFTER validate has been run and whether the form is valid. It would seem like there should be some callback or chaining method but I don't really see it in the docs. Any idea how to do this?

I have something like this:

```
  $('#signup-form-step-one').validate({
    rules: form_rules,
    messages: form_messages,
    errorClass: 'error',
    errorPlacement: function (err, element) {
      console.log('there is an error!!!!');
      setToDisabled();
      err.insertAfter(element);
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      console.log(form);
      form.submit();
    }
  });
```

and if there are any errors, set the submit button to disabled. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are dynamically updating fields then it would make sense for you to be showing us the relevant HTML markup of the form.    There are also plenty of examples about how to force validation after changing fields here on SO.  [You really missed this part of the docs?](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).  Otherwise, you'll have to give a more detailed explanation about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: As far as setting the submit to disabled, [this has already been answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+disable+submit).